# LINQ EF query issue

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am having issues with entity framework handling linq queries in my code.
Although the below query in SQL Server 2008 R2, gets me the correct set of records,
I want to know if this some issue regarding my query or something with EF, and if it is a EF issue is there a possible way to work around this.
Each table has one to many relationships. Please let me know if I need to give additional information regarding my question.

One point worth mentioning is that the Source Table has plenty of FrequencyID and CurrencyID which are Nullable, In SQL Server when I exclude the source table with Null's I get a total of 360 records, which is the result I am expecting. Somehow EF interferes here, any help will be most welcomed...

**SQL Query**

```
select 
    spa.PartnerNumber,
    sp.FirstName,
    sp.LastName,
    al.AllowanceName,
    spa.StartDate,
    spa.EndDate,
    fr.FrequencyDescription,
    cr.CurrencyCode,
    spa.Note 
from SAP2.PartnerAllowance spa
join MasterData..AllowanceMaster al on al.AllowanceMasterId = spa.AllowanceID
join SAP2.Partner sp on spa.PartnerNumber = sp.PartnerNumber
join MasterData.Currency cr on spa.CurrencyID = cr.CurrencyId
join MasterData..Frequency fr on spa.FrequencyID = fr.FrequencyID
```

**Relevant LINQ**

```
var sap2Partners = sap2Partner.Get().ToList();
var currency = sap2Currency.Get().ToList();
var frequency = sap2Frequency.Get().ToList();
var sap2PartnerAllowance = sap2PartnerAllowanceRepository.Get().ToList();
var allowance = sap2Allowance.Get().ToList();
var result = (from spa in sap2PartnerAllowance
              join spt in sap2Partners on spa.PartnerNumber equals spt.PartnerNumber
              join al in allowance on spa.AllowanceID equals al.AllowanceMasterId
              join cr in currency on spa.Currency.CurrencyId equals cr.CurrencyId
              join fr in frequency on spa.Frequency.FrequencyID equals fr.FrequencyID
              select new DataEntityUI
              {
                  PartnerNumber = spa.PartnerNumber,
                  FirstName = spt.FirstName,
                  LastName = spt.LastName,
                  AllowanceName = al.AllowanceName,
                  StartDate = String.Format(CurrentUserPreferences.DateFormat, spa.StartDate),
                  EndDate = String.Format(CurrentUserPreferences.DateFormat, spa.EndDate),
                  Amount = spa.Amount,
                  Frequency = fr.FrequencyDescription,
                  Currency = cr.CurrencyDesciption,
                  Note = spa.Note

              }).ToList();
```

Comment: Is it Linq to SQL or EF?  What excatly is the problem?

Comment: Its with the EF, I am having issues when joining the currency and Frequency Table. Like I said, I could be wrong. I am facing this for the first time.

Comment: What exactly is the error you get when running linq queries?

Comment: Hey, correct data comes later, your approach is disastrous to begin with. You are fetching entire table data of so many tables and then you are filtering. You should never do that unless u need to show entire data

Comment: I don't get any errors, get a wrong list of data.I have a screen that needs to show all data that's on a table but like I said, its only a handful records....

Comment: So what exactly is the problem: you're getting less records back with the LINQ than you are with the SQL? If so, is that not just because you're adding an extra join in the LINQ that doesn't exist in the SQL? You're also joining on FrequencyId in LINQ, but not in the SQL.

Comment: Yep that's now edited, I missed adding the last line in the query, The LINQ query works like a charm in linqpad and so does the sql query in sqlserver. The issue is with the EF

Comment: Can you provide the sql your linq query is executing? Would also like point out that you dont need to materialize your queries until you are getting what you want from the database.

Comment: Both my sql and linq queries are mentioned in the question, what I have a problem is that the EF interferes in the way I show records, My LINQ query works fine and so does the SQL query on sql server...

Comment: Reason why I say my linq query works fine is that I have used the very same query in the linqpad tool, it works fine and filters me a list of 360 records...

Comment: Your linq query will not produce the same sql you are providing, you are first materializing your tables and then doing joins on the materialized queries, thus resulting 5 separate queries in to the database. What does your Get() methods do, where are you getting your dbcontext and how the sap2x objects relate to your dbcontext?

Answer (score 0):

The line that can cause problem is:

```
String.Format(CurrentUserPreferences.DateFormat, spa.StartDate)
```

Because you are formatting the db values inside the query itself. What you can do to overcome is, fetch the result from query and then locally format the data as:

```
  var result = (from spa in sap2PartnerAllowance
                      join spt in sap2Partners on spa.PartnerNumber equals spt.PartnerNumber
                      join al in allowance on spa.AllowanceID equals al.AllowanceMasterId
                      join cr in currency on spa.Currency.CurrencyId equals cr.CurrencyId
                      join fr in frequency on spa.Frequency.FrequencyID equals fr.FrequencyID
                      select new 
                      {
                          PartnerNumber = spa.PartnerNumber,
                          FirstName = spt.FirstName,
                          LastName = spt.LastName,
                          AllowanceName = al.AllowanceName,
                          StartDate =  spa.StartDate,
                          EndDate = spa.EndDate,
                          Amount = spa.Amount,
                          Frequency = fr.FrequencyDescription,
                          Currency = cr.CurrencyDesciption,
                          Note = spa.Note

                      }).ToList();

        var result2 =result.Select(spa=>new DataEntityUI
                      {
                          PartnerNumber = spa.PartnerNumber,
                          FirstName = spa.FirstName,
                          LastName = spa.LastName,
                          AllowanceName = spa.AllowanceName,
                          StartDate = String.Format(CurrentUserPreferences.DateFormat, spa.StartDate),
                          EndDate = String.Format(CurrentUserPreferences.DateFormat, spa.EndDate),
                          Amount = spa.Amount,
                          Frequency = spa.FrequencyDescription,
                          Currency = spa.CurrencyDesciption,
                          Note = spa.Note
                      }).ToList();
```

Comment: The problem lies at the join activity, clearly currency and frequency classes are at fault, I can't seem to think that the issue is with Syntax, but hey thanks for bringing up that improvement.